# Android Toggle Button State Change On Resume

Tags: android, eclipse, togglebutton

After putting off and being lazy for a long time, I've finally decided to learn Android programming. So yeah I'm pretty much a basic n00b in it.

I created an app which toggles the phone's mode to silent and back to ringer. Now the problem that I'm facing is that if the app goes to background and when it is resumed, the state of the toggle button needs to be according to the state the phone is in.

Example:
If the phone is already in Silent mode and I launch the app, the toggle button should be pressed/activated and showing the appropriate text according to it.

Now, from what I've figured, this state setting should be done in OnCreate/OnResume, when it is checking if the Phone is silent.

Here's the code from the MainActivity.java

```
package com.SMT.silentmodetoggle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;
    private static final String TAG = "SilentModeApp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        setBUTTONCLICKLISTENER();

        Log.d("SilentModeApp", "This Is A Test");
    }

    private void setBUTTONCLICKLISTENER() {
        ToggleButton toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonview, boolean isChecked){
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
                    // Change back to normal mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                    } 
                else {
                    // Change to silent mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                    }
                    // Now toggle the UI again
                    toggleUi();
                }
         });
    }

    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
        int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;

        } 
        else {
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }
    }
        /**
        * Toggles the UI images from silent to normal and vice versa.
        */
    private void toggleUi() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;
        //ToggleButton checkTB = null;
        if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_off);
            //checkTB.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
            //checkTB.setChecked(false);
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's the info on the toggle button:

```
 <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ToggleButton1" 
        android:textOff="Toggle Silent Mode On"
        android:textOn="Toggle Silent Mode Off"
        />
```

I'm running/debugging the app on Samsung Galaxy SII I9100 running CM10.1 4.2.1

Eclipse is already set to target 4.2

All help and feedback is always welcome and valuable :)
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following after checkIfPhoneIsSilent(); in onCreate() method. Also add it in the onResume() to check the state change outside the activity.

```
 ToggleButton toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
 toggleButton1.setChecked(mPhoneIsSilent);
```

Comment: Thank you that helped correct the state. Is there any other way besides adding these lines to the code in both places?

Comment: or you can add that in the toggleUI method also.. As you call that both in  onCreate and onResume ..